# Avoid buffer underflow and overflow

Tags: c

My buffer size is 50 but I want to load my buffer only with 12 length characters
  and again I have to load my buffer with different Character length but i am not able
  to load buffer again, it is showing previous data with some garbage values.I tried to 
  remove garbage values by using hard coded value and again I reinitialized buffer to     zero value but still I am getting same problem.

This code is for receiving data in C

```
{
    if(PortRecvs(0,buff,sizeof(buff),1000)<0)               
    { 
        clrscr();
        printf("Receive Fail..");
        DelayMs(1000);
    }

    clrscr();
    printf("Receive Buff:\n%s",buff);
    DelayMs(1000);
    if(PortRecvs(0,buff,12,1000)<0)              
    { 
        clrscr();
        printf("Receive Fail..");
        DelayMs(1000);
    }
    clrscr();
    printf("Receive Buff:\n%s",buff);
    DelayMs(1000);

}
```

Comment: Note that after 'Receive Fail..' you still print out the buffer which contains no data.

Comment: Please do not tag questions both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] there are very very different answers for each, and it is frustrating when a question is not clear which language it is intended for.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many `clrscr()` calls there for good debugging.  The `DelayMs()` calls would drive me bonkers too (though some would deem driving me bonkers an unnecessary exercise).

It's a plausible inference that your `PortRecvs()` function returns the number of bytes read; you do not, however, ensure that `printf()` only prints the number of bytes that were read.  It is likely that your code should look more like:

```
{
    int nbytes;
    if ((nbytes = PortRecvs(0, buff, sizeof(buff), 1000)) < 0)               
    { 
        printf("Receive Fail.\n");
        DelayMs(1000);
    }
    else
        printf("Receive Buff: [[%.*s]]\n", nbytes, buff);  // Do not print if receive failed
    DelayMs(1000);
    if ((nbytes = PortRecvs(0, buff, 12, 1000)) < 0)              
    { 
        printf("Receive Fail.\n");
        DelayMs(1000);
    }
    else
        printf("Receive Buff: [[%.*s]]\n", nbytes, buff);
    DelayMs(1000);
}
```

Note that this code does not print the buffer if the receive fails. It ensures that each message ends with a newline. It surrounds the data with markers `[[` and `]]` (choose your own if you don't like those — I often use `<<` and `>>` instead) so that you can see more easily trailing blanks or embedded newlines.  And, most importantly, it uses the `%.*s` conversion specification to print just the number of bytes that were received from `PortRecvs()`.

Note that functions like `PortRecvs()` typically work with binary data and do not add a null terminator to the value received.  The onus is on you to ensure that you handle data without null termination correctly.